# MSAL and iOS - Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, app-store, azure-ad-msal

I have to integrate Microsoft Authentication Library ([MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc)) in my app, am I violating *section 4.8* of Apple Review Guidelines? Should I implement sign in with Apple?
I’m not sure, it is a third party login but also:

> Your app is an education, enterprise, or business app that requires
> the user to sign in with an existing education or enterprise account.

I’m confused, thanks for your help

Comment: We recently got rejected from app store with message saying our app requires sign in with Apple because we had a third party log in (Facebook). They did give us the option to defer until the next update, however, assuming that the current update was bug fixes/stability improvements only. If you have another method to sign in (besides email) you will need sign in with apple at some point or another in the near future.

Comment: Are you using MSAL for authentication against enterprise Azure Ad or Azure AD B2C.  If the former, then you do not need Sign In with Apple, however your app may be rejected for general distribution through the App Store. You may need to distribute it as a custom app

Comment: So what happened, did you integrated Apple id login along with MSAL login ? Or just MSAL alone can be used and app got reviewed and passed ?

Comment: I have integrated jus MSAL, next week I'm going to send the app for review

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 Reviewed and passed

Comment: @laucel Is the app still on the store? or were you asked to include "signin with apple"

We want to add MSAL with Azure AD authentication support